# Flash Media Server and Surround 5.1

Tags: flash, ac3

Is it possible to get a flash application streaming surround 5.1 sound?

Does Flash Media Server support Surround sound ac3 encoded 5.1 dolby surround, and if so, can i stream it via rtmp stream to a flash player that can actually play this on the supported platforms (Win, Mac etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be currently no support for Surround sound, it would have to be streamed and synchronized independently of the FMS or Wowza server. Custom flash player is also required to resolve it.